# Forwarding ports from one device to another, on different networks

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, port-forwarding, iptables-redirect

My network setup consists of 3 computers (devices A, B, C).
Devices A, B, and C are connected through ethernet using a switch.
Only device A has internet access (wifi router, with ports 8000-8002 forwarded to it).

Let's assume devices A, B and C are running an HTTP server, which I wish to access from device D, a computer somewhere on the Internet. However, device D can only access B and C through device A, requiring some port magic.

Let's assume the following addresses and jobs:

```
Device A: 
  192.168.5.100 (wlan0)  
  10.42.0.1 (eth0)
  server on port 80
Device B:
  10.42.0.2 (eth0)
  server on port 80
Device C:
  10.42.0.3 (eth0)
  server on port 80
Device D:
  somewhere on the Internet
```

How would I go about forwarding:

```
Device D -> 192.168.5.100:8000 (A) -> 10.42.0.1:80 (A)
Device D -> 192.168.5.100:8001 (A) -> 10.42.0.2:80 (B)
Device D -> 192.168.5.100:8002 (A) -> 10.42.0.3:80 (C)
```

I have tried using iptables, with different variations of commands such as

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport {from_port} -j DNAT --to-destination {to_ip}:{to_port}
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d {to_ip} -p tcp --dport {to_port} -j SNAT --to-source {from_ip}
```

where

```
from_ip is 192.168.5.100
from_port is either 8000, 8001, or 8002
to_ip is either 10.42.0.1, 10.42.0.2, or 10.42.0.3
to_port is 80
```

but I have had no success.

What am I doing wrong in the commands, or is there a better alternative to this than using iptables? If it helps, I have physical access to all 3 computers, but I have no graphical interface on device A. Devices A and B are always on Linux, while device C is sometimes on Windows, sometimes on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Enable routing
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# Forward specific ports to specific destinations
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlan0 --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.1:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlan0--dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.2:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlan0 --dport 8002 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.42.0.3:80
# Enable NAT (aka Masqurade)
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```